# Why is my pyglet program slow while rendering 128 particles?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, opengl, pyglet

Why is my program slow while rendering 128 particles? I think that's not enough to get less than 30 fps.

All I do is rendering 128 particles and giving them some basic gravitation

on_draw function

```
 def on_draw(self, time=None):
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()

    self.particles.append(Particle())
    for particle in self.particles:
        particle.draw()

        if particle.is_dead:
            self.particles.remove(particle)
```

Particle class

```
class Particle:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.acceleration = Vector2(0, 0.05)
        self.velocity = Vector2(random.uniform(-1, 1), random.uniform(-1, 0))
        self.position = Vector2()
        self.time_to_live = 255

        self.numpoints = 50

        self._vertices = []

        for i in range(self.numpoints):
            angle = math.radians(float(i) / self.numpoints * 360.0)
            x = 10 * math.cos(angle) + self.velocity[0] + 300
            y = 10 * math.sin(angle) + self.velocity[1] + 400
            self._vertices += [x, y]

    def update(self, time=None):
        self.velocity += self.acceleration
        self.position -= self.velocity
        self.time_to_live -= 2

    def draw(self):
        glEnable(GL_BLEND)
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
        glPushMatrix()
        glTranslatef(self.position[0], self.position[1], 0)
        pyglet.graphics.draw(self.numpoints, GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, ('v2f', self._vertices), ('c4B', self.color))
        glPopMatrix()

        self.update()

    @property
    def is_dead(self):
        if self.time_to_live <= 0:
            return True
        return False

    @property
    def color(self):
        return tuple(color for i in range(self.numpoints) for color in (255, 255, 255,  self.time_to_live))
```

Comment: Couple of things: your starting out with the wrong kind of OpenGL. Search for "modern opengl" and start over - currently, your code is littered with all kinds of legacy OpenGL nonsense. On each invocation of `draw` on an instance of `Particle` you redundantly update GL state, e.g. blend state - just pull that stuff out into the outer render loop. Other than that, it's not too obvious what's causing your problems, but unless you're using a GPU from 1995, it is highly likely that you're purely CPU bound (a few colored points don't stress any GL implementation or GPU these days).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not overly happy about using `GL_TRIANGLE_FAN` because it's caused a lot of odd shapes when using batched rendering. So consider moving over to `GL_TRIANGLES` instead and simply add all the points to the object rather than leaning on GL to close the shape for you.

That way, you can easily move over to doing **batched rendering**:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
from collections import OrderedDict
from time import time, sleep
from math import *
from random import randint

key = pyglet.window.key

class CustomGroup(pyglet.graphics.Group):
    def set_state(self):
        #pyglet.gl.glLineWidth(5)
        #glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE)
        #glColor4f(1, 0, 0, 1) #FFFFFF
        #glLineWidth(1)
        #glEnable(texture.target)
        #glBindTexture(texture.target, texture.id)
        pass

    def unset_state(self):
        glLineWidth(1)
        #glDisable(texture.target)

class Particle():
    def __init__(self, x, y, batch, particles):
        self.batch = batch
        self.particles = particles
        self.group = CustomGroup()

        self.add_point(x, y)

    def add_point(self, x, y):

        colors = ()#255,0,0

        sides = 50
        radius = 25

        deg = 360/sides
        points = ()#x, y # Starting point is x, y?

        prev = None
        for i in range(sides):

            n = ((deg*i)/180)*pi # Convert degrees to radians
            point = int(radius * cos(n)) + x, int(radius * sin(n)) + y

            if prev:
                points += x, y
                points += prev
                points += point
                colors += (255, i*int(255/sides), 0)*3 # Add a color pair for each point (r,g,b) * points[3 points added]

            prev = point

        points += x, y
        points += prev
        points += points[2:4]
        colors += (255, 0, 255)*3

        self.particles[len(self.particles)] = self.batch.add(int(len(points)/2), pyglet.gl.GL_TRIANGLES, self.group, ('v2i/stream', points), ('c3B', colors))

class main(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__ (self, demo=False):
        super(main, self).__init__(800, 600, fullscreen = False, vsync = True)
        #print(self.context.config.sample_buffers)
        self.x, self.y = 0, 0

        self.sprites = OrderedDict()
        self.batches = OrderedDict()
        self.batches['default'] = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
        self.active_batch = 'default'

        for i in range(1000):
            self.sprites[len(self.sprites)] = Particle(randint(0, 800), randint(0, 600), self.batches[self.active_batch], self.sprites)

        self.alive = True

        self.fps = 0
        self.last_fps = time()
        self.fps_label = pyglet.text.Label(str(self.fps) + ' fps', font_size=12, x=3, y=self.height-15)

    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == key.ESCAPE: # [ESC]
            self.alive = 0

    def render(self):
        self.clear()
        #self.bg.draw()

        self.batches[self.active_batch].draw()

        self.fps += 1
        if time()-self.last_fps > 1:
            self.fps_label.text = str(self.fps) + ' fps'
            self.fps = 0
            self.last_fps = time()

        self.fps_label.draw()
        self.flip()

    def run(self):
        while self.alive == 1:
            self.render()

            # -----------> This is key <----------
            # This is what replaces pyglet.app.run()
            # but is required for the GUI to not freeze
            #
            event = self.dispatch_events()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = main(demo=True)
    x.run()
```

Bare in mind, on my nVidia 1070 I managed to get roughly 35fps out of this code, which isn't mind blowing. But it is **1000 objects** * sides, give or take.

What I've changed is essentially this:

```
self.batch.add(int(len(points)/2), pyglet.gl.GL_TRIANGLES, self.group, ('v2i/stream', points), ('c3B', colors))
```

and in your draw loop, you'll do:

```
self.batch.draw()
```

Instead of calling `Particle.draw()` for each particle object.
What this does is that it'll send all the objects to the graphics card in one gigantic batch rather than having to tell the graphics card what to render object by object.

As @thokra pointed out, your code is more CPU intensive than GPU intensive.
Hopefully this fixes it or gives you a few pointers.

Most of this code is taking from a LAN project I did with a good friend of mine a while back:

- https://github.com/Torxed/pyslither/blob/master/main.py

Because I didn't have all your code, mainly the main loop. I applied your problem to my own code and "solved " it by tweaking it a bit. Again, hope it helps and steal ideas from that github project if you need to. Happy new year!

Comment: Oh, and if you need to update a particle position, just do change each coordinate in `self.particles[index].vertices`. If you update there, the position should update real time.

Comment: That's brilliant! I need to get deeper to OpenGL. Thank you and happy new year!